# Why can't I move when I join a server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I try to move from my spawn point I'm instantly pushed back to my spawn point. In the chat it says I must login to my account even though I'm already logged in. I even confirmed everything and secured my Mojang account. Please help!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't move from spawn location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154786/cant-move-from-spawn-location)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. You simply need to login to the server to make sure *you* are the one using your account. Every single time you join a server with this type of authentication you will need to enter into the chat:

> /login (password)

Your password can be anything. If you are wondering, the message will not be displayed to any other people. It is stored as a hash and therefore owners of servers will not be able to see your password. Just to make sure, use a password you have never used before.

If you would like to change your password, just unregister and register again.

> /unregister (password)

Remember that `/register` can be used as `/login`. So if you are on a new server, you can save time by not typing three letters.

Comment: You do not require a Mojang account to play on these servers.