# Minecraft Pocket Edition server logging in error

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I join a server I try to move but I get pushed back to my spawn point. I know I have to do the `/login (password)` thing but when I do it, I get an error during authentication.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

> This is not an error. You simply need to login to the server to make sure you are the one using your account. Every single time you join a server with this type of authentication you will need to enter into the chat:
>
> ```
> /login (password)
> ```
>
> Your password can be anything. If you are wondering, the message will not be displayed to any other people. It is stored as a hash and therefore owners of servers will not be able to see your password. Just to make sure, use a password you have never used before.
>
> If you would like to change your password, just unregister and register again.
>
> ```
> /unregister (password)
> ```
>
> Remember that /register can be used as /login. So if you are on a new server, you can save time by not typing three letters.

*written by [LameBrains](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/64760/lamebrains) on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152569/why-cant-i-move-when-a-join-a-server)*

Comment: I know that. But when I enter it, it tells me error during authentication. What I types in was /login (password) I'm not sharing my password, but obviously I typed my personal password where it says passowrd. I tried multiple times but it's not working.